# Computing $\int_{1}^{2} \frac{5x^2}{x^2 + 4x + 3} dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification, definite-integrals

$\displaystyle\int_{1}^{2} \left(5 - \frac{20x + 15}{x^2 + 4x + 3}\right) \, \mathrm{d}x $

$\displaystyle= \int_{1}^{2} 5 \, dx - \int_{1}^{2} \frac{20x + 15}{x^2 + 4x + 3} \, \mathrm{d}x$

$\displaystyle[5x]_{1}^{2} - \int_{1}^{2} \frac{20x + 15}{x^2 + 4x + 3} \, \mathrm{d}x$

$\displaystyle I= 5 - I_{1} \text{ where } I_{1} = \int_{1}^{2} \frac{20x + 15}{x^2 + 4x + 3} \, \mathrm{d}x$

$\displaystyle I_{1} = \int_{1}^{2} \frac{20x + 15}{x^2 + 4x + 8} \, \mathrm{d}x$

Let $\displaystyle 20x + 15 = A \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} (x^2 + 4x + 3) + B$

$= 2Ax + (4A + B)$

I am evaluating this integral but by this method that will be very lengthy so **any other method** **or** **any other solution(easy)** to solve this integral

Comment: Partial fractions seems like a promising way to go. I do not understand your last step; why do you differentiate the denominator?

Comment: Equating the coefficients of x and constant term we between $A=10$ $B=-25$

Comment: Not many ways to go about this integral I suppose, (very dirty) trigonometric substitution and partial fractions are the only two that come to mind... The form of the problem screams partial fraction.

Comment: Please do not make subject lines consist entirely of MathJax; it messes up some navigation shortcuts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial fractions is indeed the way to go. Yet in this case the denominator can be decomposed as
$$x^2+4x+3=(x+3)(x+1)$$ from which
$$\frac{20x+15}{x^2+4x+3}=\frac{A}{x+3}+\frac{B}{x+1}$$
from which I am sure you can take over...

Indeed your last step would apply if the denominator would not be reducible, i.e. if $\Delta<0$ as in $x^2+4x+8$.

Comment: Have you meant  ${A\over x+3}$ ? Besides, pull out the factor $5$ before applying the partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: The edit made no sense whatsover, I have reverted it.

Comment: And pulling out the $5$ in front is a plus, but is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks good to me. Note that $\frac d{dx}(x^2+4x+3)=2x+4$. Hence we are going to create $2x+4$ in the numerator,

$$\int\frac{20x + 15}{x^2 + 4x + 3}dx=\int\frac{10(2x+4)-25}{x^2+4x+3}dx=10\ln|x^2+4x+3|-25\int\frac1{(x+2)^2-1}dx$$

The last integral is equivalent to, $$\int\frac1{u^2-1}du= \frac12\ln\left|\frac{u-1}{u+1}\right|  \qquad \text{where}, \quad u= x+2$$

Note that by memorizing some famous integrals you can increase your speed in evaluating integrals. As an example see the following general forms $$\int\frac1{x^2+a^2}dx= \frac1a\arctan(\frac xa)+C$$
$$\int\frac1{x^2-a^2}dx= \frac1{2a}\ln\left|\frac{x-a}{x+a}\right|+C$$
But I recommend you to first learn how to evaluate them and then memorize them if you want.